# Cannot read property '_text' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am just trying to link react-native-fetch-blob library but it is giving error

```
react-native link react-native-fetch-blob
```

And error shows

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in ...\node_modules (48ms)
rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Cannot read property '_text' of undefined
```

I have already installed library using `npm install react-native-fetch-blob --save` but while linking it is showing error.

Not only for `fetch-blob`, linking is not working for any of the library.

Comment: Install package with `yarn`, sometimes `npm` do not work properly (in my case)

Comment: Doesn't work with that also

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are at the root of the React Native project before running `react-native link react-native-fetch-blob`.

My guess is that you may currently be within the `ios` or `android` folder, so jump back up one directory level.

If you npm installed any packages in your current directory, you will need to remove them, then install them again from the root of the project to ensure they are installed in the right location.

Comment: I am at the root only.